# Strange RFID behaviour and BSOD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers, bsod

I am experiencing a strange issue with an RFID Pad and a BSOD.

Dell Optiplex 7010, Win7, 64bit, Intel Corie 7

The issue is that I receive a BSOD just before the login screen appears. However if I unplug the RFID pad from it's USB port at start up, the PC shows the login screen and all is well. Then I need to plug in the RFID pad again. Then randomly after an unspecified period of time I will receive another BSOD.

I know this issue is related to the RFID pad as when it's removed completely I never have any issues whatsoever. There are no error logs that give me any clues as to what's going on.

The thing is, I have another Dell Optiplex 7010, exact same specs, with the exact same RFID pad and driver... which works, never any issues! So I've tried to clone this HDD, and the problem still persists. I've even replaced the motherboard.

Things I have tried so far (with no success);

- Restored pc
- Reformatted hard drive
- Re-installed minimal operating system (only Office)
- Re-installed only operating system (only Windows)
- Installed various driver versions
- Cloned an existing (working) PC
- Replaced motherboard
- Analysed error logs
- Written custom start-up/shut-down scripts (enable/disable ports at login/logout)
- Experimented with 3rd party software (devcon.exe)
- Used ENVy Computer Compare (no differences spotted)

My next step is to try a completely different make/model of PC, but that still doesn't answer my question as to why it's happening.

I've contacted the developers and apparently this is a 'known issue' which is driver-related. I'd just like to know if there's any way I can'work around' their known issue?

Can anybody else think of what the problem could be?

I have included the dump analysis if it means anything to anybody?

```
Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!IofCallDriver+14
fffff800`03288894 fe4a43          dec     byte ptr [rdx+43h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff880037b6d28 -- (.exr 0xfffff880037b6d28)
ExceptionAddress: fffff80003288894 (nt!IofCallDriver+0x0000000000000014)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000001
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000043
Attempt to write to address 0000000000000043

CONTEXT:  fffff880037b6580 -- (.cxr 0xfffff880037b6580)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=fffffa8015800000 rcx=fffffa800aa25050
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=00000000fffff88a rdi=00000000fffff88a
rip=fffff80003288894 rsp=fffff880037b6f60 rbp=fffffa800aa25050
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=fffff880033e4180 r10=fffffa80066f88e0
r11=fffffa80077bac60 r12=0000000000000001 r13=0000000000000003
r14=fffffa800aa25050 r15=0000000000000001
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
nt!IofCallDriver+0x14:
fffff800`03288894 fe4a43          dec     byte ptr [rdx+43h] ds:002b:00000000`00000043=??
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000043

WRITE_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800034bb100
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800034bb1c0
 0000000000000043 Nonpaged pool

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
ftdibus+85fb
fffff880`064aa5fb ??              ???

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7E

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff880064aa5fb to fffff80003288894

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`037b6f60 fffff880`064aa5fb : fffffa80`15800000 fffffa80`0aa25050 fffffa80`15800000 fffff880`04f632d9 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x14
fffff880`037b6f90 fffffa80`15800000 : fffffa80`0aa25050 fffffa80`15800000 fffff880`04f632d9 fffffa80`15800000 : ftdibus+0x85fb
fffff880`037b6f98 fffffa80`0aa25050 : fffffa80`15800000 fffff880`04f632d9 fffffa80`15800000 fffffa80`fffff88a : 0xfffffa80`15800000
fffff880`037b6fa0 fffffa80`15800000 : fffff880`04f632d9 fffffa80`15800000 fffffa80`fffff88a fffffa80`00000100 : 0xfffffa80`0aa25050
fffff880`037b6fa8 fffff880`04f632d9 : fffffa80`15800000 fffffa80`fffff88a fffffa80`00000100 fffff880`037b6fe0 : 0xfffffa80`15800000
fffff880`037b6fb0 fffff880`00000001 : fffffa80`0ae411b0 ffff0000`05318326 fffffa80`0ab96e90 00000000`00000001 : usbhub!UsbhFdoDeviceControl+0x1a5
fffff880`037b7010 fffffa80`0ae411b0 : ffff0000`05318326 fffffa80`0ab96e90 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`0ab9c830 : 0xfffff880`00000001
fffff880`037b7018 ffff0000`05318326 : fffffa80`0ab96e90 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`0ab9c830 fffff880`064aa8b7 : 0xfffffa80`0ae411b0
fffff880`037b7020 fffffa80`0ab96e90 : 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`0ab9c830 fffff880`064aa8b7 fffffa80`0ae411b0 : 0xffff0000`05318326
fffff880`037b7028 00000000`00000001 : fffffa80`0ab9c830 fffff880`064aa8b7 fffffa80`0ae411b0 fffffa80`0aa25050 : 0xfffffa80`0ab96e90
fffff880`037b7030 fffffa80`0ab9c830 : fffff880`064aa8b7 fffffa80`0ae411b0 fffffa80`0aa25050 fffffa80`0ae411b0 : 0x1
fffff880`037b7038 fffff880`064aa8b7 : fffffa80`0ae411b0 fffffa80`0aa25050 fffffa80`0ae411b0 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffffa80`0ab9c830
fffff880`037b7040 fffffa80`0ae411b0 : fffffa80`0aa25050 fffffa80`0ae411b0 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0ab96e90 : ftdibus+0x88b7
fffff880`037b7048 fffffa80`0aa25050 : fffffa80`0ae411b0 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0ab96e90 fffffa80`0000016d : 0xfffffa80`0ae411b0
fffff880`037b7050 fffffa80`0ae411b0 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0ab96e90 fffffa80`0000016d 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffffa80`0aa25050
fffff880`037b7058 00000000`00000000 : fffffa80`0ab96e90 fffffa80`0000016d 00000000`00000000 fffff880`037b70c8 : 0xfffffa80`0ae411b0


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  ftdibus+85fb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: ftdibus

IMAGE_NAME:  ftdibus.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  46826082

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xfffff880037b6580 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_ftdibus+85fb

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_ftdibus+85fb

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Any advice or suggestions are very welcome :)

Comment: Everything you've outlined here is almost perfect. However your post is lacking one critical piece of information. if you could "pretty please" provide the BSOD details or information related to any event logs, it would be greatly beneficial to resolving this issue.

Comment: look for an update of the driver **ftdibus.sys**

Answer (score 0):

> EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx"
>   referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

There are a few potential issues which may be causing this exception to occur.

1. It could be memory which is going bad  (maybe, this would persist through os reinstalls)

   - Try removing one of the memory components from the machine and/or replacing.
2. Outdated drivers (possibly)

   - Visit the manufacture's website, download a newer driver.
   - Attempt to downgrade the OS and see if the issue still exists.
3. Potential hardware conflicts (possibly)

   - Unplug any other devices from the machine and see if the error goes away.
4. Or a system related issue (unlikely)

   - Run sfc /scannow from the cmd shell.